# Why can't you generalize parametric classes?

Tags: java, parameters, parametric-polymorphism

When you define parametric classes you can only use a fixed number of parameters.

```
class Container<T> {
    ...
}
```

However, if you want to create, say, a Map with multiple values. You must use a `Map<K, List<V>>` instead of `Map<K, V1, V2, V3>`. **Why can't you define something like?**

```
class Map<K, V, ...> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: First and foremost, because a `Map` takes a key and a value. What you're describing doesn't look to be a `Map`.

Comment: Also, how would you use it? Even if you were allowed to do `SomeClass<T1, T2 ... TN>`, you can hardly generate fields `T1 t1; T2 t2; ... TN tn;`

Answer (score 3):

You can, if you implement a `Tuple` class with 3 elements.

```java
class Tuple3<T1, T2, T3> {
    private final T1 t1;
    private final T2 t2;
    private final T3 t3;

    // constructor, getters, ...
}
```

Then you can use it:

```java
Map<K, Tuple3<V1, V2, V3>>
```

It is not the responsibility of `Map` to support multiple types of *values*. See [separation of concerns (SoC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) for more information on that topic.